# How to allow external users access Onpremise app configured with Azure App proxy and SAML SSO

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have configured Onpremise app with Azure App proxy and SAML SSO.

I'm able to access the application using application user access url. I have assigned my organization Azure AD group to onpremise application, so all users in that group able to access application.

Now, I want to allow external users (gmail,hotmail,yahoo etc.) access to the application.

I have large list of external users, who needs access to the application.

How can I provide access to all external users for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Azure Active Directory - B2C`. This allows external users to use their preferred social, enterprise, or local account identities to get single sign-on access to your applications and APIs. Refer to the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview